# Can you finish a sentence with "for the now"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Can you finish a sentence with "for the now"?

> "So we will resolve your case for the now?"

This sounds old fansioned to me. However, is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

It *is* an idiom, and somewhat old-fashioned but still used.

An example I found in a Google search:

> There is often way too much talk of building for the future but what about building for the now?

If you Google the expression you'll find more examples. It is just a way of differentiating between "now" as a temporary state and "now" as a concept of *current time*. For example:

> He is living for now.

This suggests that a person is alive at this moment, but might be dead later.

> He is living for *the* now.

This idiomatically means that a person is living their life in such a way that they consider only the present time, not so much the future.